# React react-doc-viewer

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, docx

I have a problem opening xlsx and doc documents in docViewer. Pdfy, photos opens normally. File paths are good because pdf files opens. The only problem with the console I got was https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/en-PL/strings.js not found. From what I saw, all the examples on the internet work, I looked at the other posts about the viewer, but nothing helped me. Does anybody have an idea ?

```
  import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText, CardLink } from 'reactstrap'
import DocViewer, {DocViewerRenderers} from "react-doc-viewer"
const testURL2 = "http://10.0.1.31:7764/documentations/test-excelaki.xlsx"
const testURL3 = "http://10.0.1.31:7761/BasFLOW_pliki/testEOD/test-doc.doc"
const testURL4 = "http://10.0.1.31:7761/BasFLOW_pliki/testEOD/test-excelaki.xlsx"
const testPDF = "http://10.0.1.31:7764/files/KorektyKalendarzyINS.pdf"
const testExcel = "http://eod:7764/files/TJMmalarnia.xlsx"
// http://eod:7766/login
const DTinstruction = () => {
  const docs = [{ uri: testPDF, fileType: "pdf"}, {uri:testExcel, fileType: "xlsx"}, {uri:"http://10.0.1.31:7761/BasFLOW_pliki/testEOD/test-doc.doc", fileType: "docx"}, {uri:"http://10.0.1.31:7761/BasFLOW_pliki/testEOD/test-excelaki.xlsx", fileType: "xlsx"}, {uri:"http://10.0.1.31:7764/files/sample.png", fileType: "png"}]
  //http://10.0.1.31:7761/BasFLOW_pliki/SBS\Img\09.2022\21-09-2022-03-04-34nitownice.png
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>Wybierz aplikacje dt</CardTitle>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
      <DocViewer
         documents={docs} 
         //  theme={{
           //   primary: "#5296d8",
           //   secondary: "#ffffff",
           //   tertiary: "#5296d899",
           //   text_primary: "#ffffff",
           //   text_secondary: "#5296d8",
           //   text_tertiary: "#00000099",
           //   disableThemeScrollbar: false
           // }}
           config={{
             header: {
               disableHeader: false,
               disableFileName: false,
               retainURLParams: false
              }
            }}
            pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
          style={{ height: 500 }}
        />
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default DTinstruction
```

Comment: @KJ thanks, but is not a problem, i change url and still document is not open

Comment: @KJ thank you probably this is the main reason why it is not playing files xlsx and docx